# Determining if an attribute is absent via CSS Attribute Selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can the CSS Attribute Selector, and/or combination of selectors, be used to determine if an attribute is *absent*?

An attribute selector can be used to test if the attribute is blank:

```
[aria-label='']
```

... but the attribute still must be *present* in order for that to pass. If the HTML tag does not have the attribute at all, the above selector does not pass.

Can a selector be written in a way that it would pass if the attribute is *not there*?

Comment: Specification: [Attribute presence and value selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
div:not([aria-label]) {
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div aria-label="test">
  test
</div>

<div>
  test2
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and it's quite simple with the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class:

```css
span:not([wrong]) {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<span>I have no attribute</span><br/>
<span wrong>I have the wrong attribute :-(</span>
```

Comment: Thank you! 3 folks with quick answers showing I'm not required to use the '=' in the selector.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a combination of the attribute selector and `:not()` negation pseudo-class:

```css
div[orange] { background-color: orange; }                       /* 1 */

div:not([orange]) { background-color: lightgreen; }             /* 2 */

div { height: 50px; }
```

```html
<div>Does not have the orange attribute</div>
<div orange>Has the orange attribute</div>
<div green>Does not have the orange attribute</div>
<div orange="orange">Has the orange attribute</div>
```

Notes:

1. Target divs with `orange` attribute.
2. Target divs that do not have the `orange` attribute.

References:

- [CSS Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)
- [The `:not()` negation pseudo-class](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation)

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realized I could use the attribute without a comparation operator.